# how to reverse a string in c

Tags: c, reverse

I am facing this problem I can't get it to work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void RecursiveReverse(char word)
{
    if (word == '\0')
        return;

    RecursiveReverse(word + sizeof(word));

    printf("%c", word);
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("enter a word please =>"); 
    char toBeRev;
    scanf("%s", toBeRev); 

    RecursiveReverse(toBeRev);

    printf("\n");
}
```

I am supposed to request for a word, and send it to a function to get it reversed.

Comment: show us your function reverse ...

Comment: StackOverflow does not work like that. You have to show us what have you done so far. Then we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: its under the void reverse but I do not know what to put in to generate the reversing stuff.

Comment: this is my editted one

Comment: No , this ain't the right way buddy, you are new so read this page :http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: i edited it. is this the proper way to ask?

Comment: Yes but you should also try it, your         scanf("%s", toBeRev); should throw some errors

Comment: so i put toBeRev as array?

Comment: @PEARR yes who can contain the user input (check my answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First mistake you do something like:

```
char toBeRev; 
scanf("%s", toBeRev);
```

so you try to fill toBeRev with the user input but %s take a `char*` and not `char`

So you must have a buffer who can contain the input of the user.

```
char input[4096] = {0};
```

Then you say that you just need to print the string in a reverse order, so you don't need to change the value of your string, and you started with a recursive function (which is a good idea)

I have done something according to your exemple

```
  void reverse(const char *str) //you don't need to modify your string
   { 
      if (*str != '\0') //if the first character is not '\O' 
        reverse((str + 1)); // call again the function but with +1 in the pointer addr
      printf("%c", *str); // then print the character
    }

int main()
{
  char input[4096] = {0};

  printf("Enter a word please => ");
  scanf("%s", input);
  reverse(input);
  printf("\n");
  return (0);
}
```

so if the input is 'Hi', in the input you will have ['H']['I']['\0']

first call to reverse the string is ['H']['I']['\0']
second call the string will be ['I']['\0']
tird call ['\0']
and then you print the first character of the string so
IH

Answer (score 0):

Example implementation:

```
void reverse(char str[]) {    
    int i;
    char c;
    int len = strlen(str);

    for (i=0; i< len/2; i++) {
        c = str[i];
        str[i] = str[len - i - 1];
        str[len - i - 1] = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the meaning of strlen(str)?
I dont quite get the for part 

sorry. I am very new to c programming.

Comment: a correct 'c' style string is ended with '\0'. strlen() simple counts how many characters are in the table before this '\0'. strlen is part of the library string.h (you have the header already included).

Comment: for the c part, that means the string of word for eg apple is stored in str[i]? could you explain step by step how the for loop works?

Comment: apple is something like this { 'a' , 'p' , 'p' , 'l' , 'e' , '\0' }, this is why the strlen can recognize a number of characters in the 'str'. In for loop you go via half of the string and exchange the characters with other half :)

Comment: when u str[i] it will be  { 'a' , 'p' , 'p' , 'l' , 'e' , '\0' } then it will become  { 'a' , 'p' , 'p' , 'l' , '\0' } ?

Comment: str[i] refers to one character ( str[0]='a' , str[1]='p' .... ) . 'i' is an offset inside of 'str' table.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void RecursiveReverse(char* word, int len) {
    printf("%c", *word);

    if(len <= 0)
        return;

    RecursiveReverse(--word,--len);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char toBeRev[64];
    printf("Enter a word please => ");
    scanf("%s", toBeRev);

    RecursiveReverse(toBeRev + strlen(toBeRev), strlen(toBeRev));

    return 0;
}
```

The above should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

string reverse recursive yet ... :

```
void StrReverse (char *str)
{
    if(*str)
    {
        StrReverse(str+1);
        putchar(*str);
    }
}
```